# маркеры из локальной базы данных

Tags: android, mysql, json

Как правильно сделать запрос для вывода маркеров на андроид устройстве (на google maps). Я подключаюсь к json, но ничего не происходит. Подскажите, как это делается.

**Обновление**

Вот [ссылка](http://wewdemo.esy.es/create_product.php) на json, мне нужно вывести маркеры в приложении.

Comment: Вам надо маркеры поставить на карте?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид  именно, только геоданные из локальной бд

Comment: Запрос куда и на что? Почему что то должно происходить когда вы к чему то подключаетесь? Телепаты в отпуске так что придется вам задать вопрос более развернуто что бы вам смогли помочь.

Comment: Ок, что вы делаете что бы реализовать то что вам нужно, и что конкретно при этом не получается? На этом сайте не пишут на заказ реализации приложений или их компонентов,здесь помогают решать проблемы возникающие при их написании.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить маркер можно так:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
    .title("Hello world"));
```

Вам необходимо из ответа с сервера вытянуть координаты и добавить на карту:

```
private void fun(GoogleMap map, String response) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("markers");
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject item = arr.get(i);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(item.get("lat"), item.get("lng")))
                .title("Hello world"));
    }
}
```